# Given $a_1,\dots ,a_n\in V$, the set $W$ of all linear combinations of $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ is a subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have to prove the following:

> Given $a_1,\dots ,a_n\in V$, the set $W$ of all linear combinations of $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ is a subspace of $V$.

I'm having a little bit of trouble because the two notions seems to be the same, but I guess the solution is as follows:

1. From the definition of vector space, for each $a,b\in V$, $a+b\in V$ and $\alpha a\in V$.
2. Then for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \dots \alpha_n $ we have $\alpha_1 a_1+ \alpha_2a_2+ \dots \alpha_na_n \in V $ as a consequence of successive aplications of $1$ and we have $\alpha_1 a_1+ \alpha_2a_2+ \dots \alpha_na_n\in W$ by definition. From this, we obtain that $V=W$ and hence, as $V$ is a subspace of $V$, then $V$ is a subspace of $W$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: That $W$ is a vector space seems like an assumption of the problem. $W$ is certainly contained in $V$, but they need not be equal. Since $W$ is a subset of $V$ which is itself a vector space, it is a subspace.

Comment: Sorry, how can they not be equal? I mean, $W$ is the set of all linear combinations of the vectors in $V$. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: But the vectors may not be many "enough" to generate all the vectors in $V.$

Comment: Does an arbitrary collection of vectors in $V$ have to be a spanning set?

Comment: Yes! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

We just need to show that W is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  So let $v , w \in W$, then $v = a_1v_1 + ... + a_n v_n$ and $w = b_1v_1 + ... + b_n v_n$ so $cv = ca_1v_1 + ... + ca_nv_n \in W$ and $v + w =(a_1 + b_1)v_1+...+ (a_n + b_n)v_n \in W$.